# Android studio - Emulator: Couldn't statvfs() path Error

Tags: android-emulator

When I want to run my android app by emulator in the Android Studio 3.2, I have this error. I just want to run the Hello world example.

```
Emulator: Couldn't statvfs() path
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and realized i forgot to install the official nvidia video card drivers.