# Emulator: Couldn't statvfs() path: No such file or directory

Tags: android

I am new to android and when I run hello world project in emulator, I got this error:

`Emulator: Couldn't statvfs() path: No such file or directory`

But I can start the virtual device successfully.
I have no idea what is going on. It seems a path error.

My Android Studio is 3.3 and my system is Ubuntu 18.04lts. 
The virtual device is Nexus 5X API 28, android 9.0. I also tried other virtual devices but nothing worked.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127093/android-studio-emulator-couldnt-statvfs-path-error